# ¿Como generar la parte inferior del rombo? Pseint- C

Tags: c, pseint

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
float f;
float i;
float n;
float v;
printf("ingrese tamaño del rombo (Debe ser mayor que 1)\n");
scanf("%f",&n);
for (i=1;i<=n;i+=1) {
    for (f=0;f<=n-i;f+=1) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (v=1;v<=i+(i-1);v+=1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
for (i=n-1;i<=1;i+=1) {
    for (f=n-i;f<=0;f+=1) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (v=i+(i-1);v<=1;v+=1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Quisiera saber por que al convertir el Pseudocodigo en Pseint a C solamente me sale la parte superior del rombo, adjunto el Pseudocodigo correspondiente:

Algoritmo punto5

```
    Escribir 'ingrese tamaño del rombo (Debe ser mayor que 1)'
    Leer n
    Para i<-1 Hasta n Hacer
        Para f<-0 Hasta n-i Hacer
            Escribir ' ' Sin Saltar
        FinPara
        Para v<-1 Hasta i+(i-1) Hacer
            Escribir '*' Sin Saltar
        FinPara
        Escribir ' '
    FinPara
    Para i<-n-1 Hasta 1 Hacer
        Para f<-n-i Hasta 0 Hacer
            Escribir ' ' Sin Saltar
        FinPara
        Para v<-i+(i-1) Hasta 1 Hacer
            Escribir '*' Sin Saltar
        FinPara
        Escribir 
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> solamente me sale la parte superior del rombo

Porque es exáctamente lo que pides en tu código, mira el segundo bucle:

```
for (i=n-1;i<=1;i+=1) {
    for (f=n-i;f<=0;f+=1) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (v=i+(i-1);v<=1;v+=1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

Desde `n-1` hasta que se alcance `1`: suma `1`. Suponiendo que `n` sea `5`, el bucle hace lo siguiente:

1. Asigna el valor `n-1` a `i`; le asigna `4`.
2. Comprueba que `i` sea menor o igual a `1` (`4` no es menor o igual a `1`).
3. Fin.

---

Conceptualmente la segunda colección de bucles es incorrecta. La parte inferior del rombo usa valores descendentes pero tus bucles sólo incrementan valores, si le das la vuelta  a las comparaciones y los signos del segundo bucle tendrás el resultado que buscas:

```
for (i=n-1;i>=1;i-=1) {
    for (f=n-i;f>=0;f-=1) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (v=i+(i-1);v>=1;v-=1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Tu código es difícil de leer y confuso, por eso es fácil cometer errores y complicado encontrarlos, te aconsejo lo siguiente:

- **Usa nombres de variables auto-explicativos**: Las variables cuyo nombre es una sola letra aportan muy poca información sobre cuál es su cometido, es mucho mejor usar nombres descriptivos y claros.
- **Deja respirar a tu código**: En los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, por entonces era necesario apelotonar el código para que cupiera la mayor cantidad en pantalla; esos tiempos quedaron atrás, ya no hay necesidad de redactar código como si te cobraran por cada espacio puesto.

Siguiendo los consejos anteriores, y usando los parámetros de formato de [`printf`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) para ahorrarnos bucles tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int filas;
    int fila = 0;

    printf("ingrese tamaño del rombo (Debe ser mayor que 1)\n");
    scanf("%d",&filas);

    for (; fila != filas; ++fila) {
        printf("%*s%.*s\n", 5 - fila, "", ((fila + 1) * 2) - 1, "************");
    }

    for (; fila != -1; --fila) {
        printf("%*s%.*s\n", 5 - fila, "", ((fila + 1) * 2) - 1, "************");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CEuXmA9njAvdr11l).

Answer (score 0):

La parte de abajo está mal. Como observó PaperBirdMaster tus bucles sólo incrementan valores, si le das la vuelta a las comparaciones y los signos del segundo bucle tendrás el resultado que buscas:

Por lo tanto, lo que hay que hacer es juestamnte eso, usar for con paso negativo para completar la parte de abajo del rombo:

Aquí el código corregido de la parte de abajo:

```
    for (i=n-1;i>=1;i-=1) {
        for (f=n-i;f>=0;f-=1) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (v=i+(i-1);v>=1;v-=1) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En cuanto a PSeInt, no se que perfil tienes configurado, pero no especificas que el paso es negativo en los boques Para. Por otro lado la sentencia Escribir requiere argumentos.

corregido el código quedaría así:

```
Para i<-n-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso -1 Hacer
    Para f<-n-i Hasta 0 Con Paso -1 Hacer
        Escribir ' ' Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    Para v<-i+(i-1) Hasta 1 Con Paso -1 Hacer
        Escribir '*' Sin Saltar;
    FinPara
    Escribir ""; 
FinPara
Escribir "";
```